# Tell rspec to not run pending tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Is there a way to turn off outputting pending tests in Rspec (rspec 3, specifically)? Rather than having to tag everyone and skipping them.

Perhaps a --pending type command for .rspec?

Answer (score -1):

If you want a spec not to be run at all in rspec 3 you should use `skip` rather than `pending`